# Mongodb nodejs lambda connections maxed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, database-connection

I have a problem with my MongoDB Atlas. I am running Atlas version 3.4 instance version M20. The environment I'm working in is AWS Lambda architecture with several services querying the database. For some reason, the database reaches its max connections (700 connections) in a few minutes and then crashes.

Currently I'm using this set of options to run the DB:

I have tried some solutions I found online - using

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

and setting the database as a singleton using dbpools but still cant keep the connections low.

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const log = require('./logger');

let cachedDbs = {};

module.exports.get = async uri => {
  let cachedDb = cachedDbs[uri];

  if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
    return cachedDb;
  }

  log.info('Getting db connection to', uri);

  const client = await mongo.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    appname: process.env.SERVICE_NAME,
    reconnectTries: 5,
    poolSize: 5,
    maxIdleTimeMS: 1000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 1000,
    waitQueueTimeoutMS: 1000
  });
  cachedDb = await client.db();
  cachedDbs[uri] = cachedDb;

  return cachedDb;
};
```

Has anyone had this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something must be wrong with your caching logic that's causing you to call `mongo.connect` each time this method is called. You just need to debug it.

Comment: thanks for the response, doesnt the fact that we are reusing the same connection the same as connecting only on startup?

Comment: Should be, but how often is `Getting db connection to...` logged?

Comment: You're supposed to connect to mongodb once and use that connection not connect every http request!

Comment: @JohnnyHK do you have any idea how to debug the connection pool using the MongoDB shell? getting info regarding the connection source? we found only the IP of the connection but because we use AWS Lambda that doesnt really help..

Comment: How many concurrent AWS Lambda invocations are you running? Each concurrent invocation of the Lambda function will run in a separate container, and will be unable to share database connections with each other. If you have 700 concurrent invocations of your Lambda function you will have 700 database connections (and there is no way to avoid that).